# Let $G$ be a group and $H\le G$ and $a\in G$. which ones are always correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group, $H\neq G$ and $H\le G$ and $a\in G$. which ones are always correct?

**a)** $|a|=|a^{-1}|$

**b)** H and G has the same unit

**c)** $|H|\neq0$

**d)** if        $a^{12}=a^2$ then |a| is even number

**e)** $\langle \langle a\rangle\cup H\rangle$  is a subgroup of G.

b and c is correct because $H\le G$

for d, if $|G|=m, m|(12-2)$ and $|a|$ divides $m$ so |a| can be 5

Comment: what is $|a|$ ??

Comment: @Surb order of a

Comment: Why do you think (c) is correct? If $H$ is a subgroup, then it contains the identity, meaning it's nonempty and has order at least 1...

Comment: then a) is correct. Indeed, let $n=|a|$. $$1=aa^{-1}\implies \underbrace{a^n}_{=1}(a^{-1})^n=1\implies (a^{-1})^n=1$$

Comment: @coldnumber sorry it was a misspell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a)

$e=(aa^{-1})^n=a^na^{-n}$, so if one is $e$ the other must also be $e$, so it is true.

b)

the identity is the only idempotent element in $G$, (since $xx=x\implies x^{-1}xx=x^{-1}x\implies x=e$) and the unit of $H$ must be idempotent also.

c)

Since $H$ has an identity it has at least one element.

d)

$e$ satisfies $|e^{12}|=|e^2|$ and $|e|=1$. So no.

For another example consider $\mathbb Z_{31}$ and $a=2$. Notice $2(2)=4$ and $12(2)=24$ both have order $31$, while $2$ also has order $31$.

e)

By definition $\langle S \rangle $ is a subgroup of $G$ for any subset $S$ of $G$. the subset $\langle a\rangle \cup H$ is no exception.

Comment: thanks. isnt it the same? in $(Z_{12},\oplus )$ if we  take $H=\{0,4,8\}$ and $K=\{0,6\}$ .$H\oplus K \leq Z_{12}$ and $<H\cup K>=<H,K>=H\oplus K=\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ is it wrong?   and for the d) what if $a \neq e$ is it also wrong? sorry for the latex

Comment: I added an example in which $a\neq e$.  Which problem are you reffering to when you mention $\mathbb Z_{12}$?

Comment: the last one. since "$<a>\cap H \in G$ then $<<a>\cap H > $ is subgroup of G " is true but the example you gave in the first place with 2Z and 3Z was seemed also true to me. is my example that I wrote in comment with $<H\cap K>$ wrong?

Comment: That is because I only took $H\cup K$ and forgot to take the subgroup generated by $H\cup K$ which is $\langle H\cup K\rangle$. It doesn't matter what goes inside the "$\langle \rangle$", it is always going to be a subgroup, by definition.

Comment: I got it $5\in <2Z\cup 3Z>$ but $5\notin 2Z\cup 3Z$ .thanks again

Comment: Exactly, no problem. Happy to help.

Comment: e) is *of course* always true because $\langle a\rangle\cup H$ is a subsets of $G$ and $\langle \langle a\rangle\cup H\rangle$ is *by definition* the subgroup generated by this subset